# Prevent user from entering negative number validation material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

How can I prevent the user from adding a negative number to my table? I thought that having the type: numeric would do the trick but I still can enter a negative number into it.

Could I create a function and added to my promise?

```
<MaterialTable
        aria-label="List of pseudopotentials"
        icons={tableIcons}
        title="Pseudopotentials"
        columns={[
          {title: 'Element', field: 'kind', editable: 'never'},
          {title: 'Atomic Mass (AMU)', field: 'atomic_mass', type: 'numeric'}, <----- TYPE NUMERIC HERE
          {title: 'Filename', field: 'filename', editable: 'never'},
        ]}
        data={createTable(selectedPseudos, customAtomicMasses)}
        options={{
          paging: false,
          rowStyle: (x: {tableData: {id: number}}) => {
            if (x.tableData.id % 2) {
              return {backgroundColor: '#ddd'}
            }
          },
          maxBodyHeight: '25em',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#ddd',
            padding: '0.25em 1em',
            fontWeight: 'bolder',
          },
        }}
        editable={{
          /** NEED TO PREVENT NEGATIVE NUMBER*/
          onRowUpdate: (newData) =>
            new Promise((resolve) => {
              const newMasses = {...customAtomicMasses}
              newMasses[newData.kind] = newData.atomic_mass
              setCustomAtomicMasses(newMasses)
              resolve(0)
            }),
        }}
        actions={[
          {
            icon: () => {
              return <Search aria-label="search-pseudopotentials" />
            },
            tooltip: 'Search pseudopotentials',
            onClick: (_event, rowData) => {
              setModalKind(rowData.kind)
              setShowModal(true)
            },
          },
        ]}
      ></MaterialTable>
```

Comment: Can you try to explain further what your actual question is. You shared what you tried (good!) also share why that *didn't* work. Symptoms are important.

Comment: If you want to get good answers to your question, you should edit your question to include the information you left in the comment, elaborate if you an with more code and also include the _full_ error message.